# DotNetNuke Scalability

Tags: scalability, dotnetnuke

We are about to start in a content-rich web site and we are considering Dotnetnuke. 
The site will be multilingual with size compared to that of the UN site (http://www.un.org/en/index.shtml )
The question is: Would DotNetNuke support such large content size? is there a limit on the size of content or the depth of the hierarchy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DotNetNuke is very scalable, but as with any application you need to be considerate of the hardware you have things running on. Proper planning up front will help you to alleviate any potential load issues.

As for content and the depth of content, portals, pages, modules, you can create as much depth as is necessary, keeping in mind the hierarchy of content can lead to potential concerns about ease of management of that content.

Answer (score 3):

In our company we run about 50 instances with over 150 portals in DotNetNuke. Some of them have lots of content with lots of user (>100000 users). So far we never had a problem with any of them in terms of performance. I don't know of any limitations regards content depth or similar.